# how to control json entries when fetch it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

my code showing the image and title and summary for all json file entries all what i need to show the image , title and summary to the first entry only and will show title to other entries.

please advise.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>

$(function() {

var entries = [];
var dmJSON = "http://localhost:8080/Newfolder/test.json";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
   $.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.image + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.summary + "</td>" + "</tr>"
       $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
 });

});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
<table id= "entrydata" border="1">
<thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>UserName</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    <th>Location</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

please fine my updated code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>

$(function() {

var items = [];
var dmJSON = "http://localhost:8080/Newfolder/realaljazeera.json";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
   $.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
    if (i == 0) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<img src="+f.Image3+"/>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Title + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Summary + "</td>" + "</tr>"
    } else {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Title + "</td>" + "</tr>"
    }
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
});

});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
<table id= "entrydata" border="2" style="width:680px;">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you clarify your question? you're saying you have a bug that only title will show for all entries except the first, or that is what you want to happened? or something else?

Comment: please could you find my updates u will know what i mean

Comment: Please don't rewrite your question with the answer. Now no one can see what the original problem was.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
    if (i == 0) {
        var tblRow = // what you want for first entry
    } else {
        var tblRow = // what you want for other entries
    }
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
});
```

Comment: After seeing your answer I understood the question.

Comment: i am facing below error :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: I left out the parenthesis at the end, fixed it now.

Comment: its also not showing any results 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ?????  jquery.min.js:16      shall i have different libary ?

Comment: That means that `data.entries` is undefined. Are you sure that's the name of the property in the returned JSON? If it worked in your original code, it should work the same with this replacement.

Comment: Please add the new code to the end of your question.

Comment: I don't see any difference between your original code and my code that would explain why `data.entries` is undefined in my code, but not in your code.

Comment: yes i just change the if statment as you see please advise what to do

Comment: What does `console.log(data.entries)` show in the new version?